# Camera not working on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, motorola

I have an application for Motorola MC9500 series that uses the device camera.

I use the following method to init the Imager:

```
        Symbol.Generic.Device MyDevice;
        int i = 0;

        if (imager == null)
        {
            MyDevice = (Symbol.Generic.Device)Symbol.Imaging.Device.AvailableDevices.GetValue(0);

            for (i = 1; MyDevice != null; i++)
            {

                if (MyDevice.FriendlyName.Equals("Image Capture Driver for Color Camera"))
                    break;

                MyDevice = (Symbol.Generic.Device)Symbol.Imaging.Device.AvailableDevices.GetValue(i);

            }

            if (MyDevice == null)
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("Camera não foi encontrada.");
                this.Close();
                return;
            }

            imager = new Symbol.Imaging.Imager(MyDevice);
        }
```

It works fine on WM6.1 but not on WM6.5, where the last line throws the following exception:

**Failed to create Imager: IMAGE_Open failed: E_IMG_INVALIDDEVICE**

According to the manufacturer documentation, this means: "The physical device driver (PDD). DLL did not contain the required entry points.". However, I have all the drivers up-to-date. They can be found on: http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=12683&sliceId=&dialogID=469856149&stateId=1%200%20469852171

When I'm running the program, I have no other tasks running, since I thought this could be due to another process locking the camera to itself.

Relevant fact is that the camera doesn't seem to work/start in any other application that uses it. However, they seem to work on my client's device (also WM6.5, same device).

Anyone got any suggestion or idea of why this happens, or how to solve it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly? The problem is on your test device only but not on the customer's devices? If so, reflash/wipe your device and start from scratch. I often got problems with a device that I use to develop day to day and sometimes needs a wipe to get my code working.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but if I'm not confusing things, we didn't got a solution; however it magically worked when we changed to another device with another version of WM6.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but mine was caused because I also had a Barcode scanner active, disabling the Barcode scanner fixed this for me.

```
barcode2.Disable()
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit?
We don't use the barcode scanner, how did you instantiate barcode2?

Comment: If you don't use the barcode scanner then that won't be the issue I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install a CAB to enable second source camera from motorola site (SPR23173).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Motorola MC75A.  Turns out it was the Datawedge application that was also installed on the device that was stopping it from working correctly.  The camera and the barcode scanner appear to be kind of linked.  You can only use one at once and as the DataWedge was already running, my code/project was producing the IMAGE_Open failed: E_IMG_INVALIDDEVICE.  Simply going into DataWedge and stopping the process fixed  this instantly.